# XSLT 2 : How to pass an input stream as a parameter to XSL sheet

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am using Saxon HE 10
(using Xslt30Transformer)

How to pass input stream as a parameter to XSL?

I see there is a setStylesheetParameters . How to send input stream , as this expects object of type XdmValue?

I used to set the file name parameter , trying to pass the stream instead
<xsl:param name="test" select="'test.xml'"/>

Comment: Why would your XSLT 2 code need to receive and work with a stream? If you use the Java or C# API to set parameters and want to set an XdmNode parameter parsed from a stream you can use the DocumentBuilder to parse the stream into an XdmNode and pass that in.

Comment: I think if you really want the XSLT to deal with a stream you would rather have a URL resolver that makes sure a certain URI argument to e.g. `doc()` reads from that stream.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for you inputs . I was able to achieve this using  URIResolver.. Basically got Document form input stream , set this as parameter. SetURI resolver in transformer .            transformer.setURIResolver((href, base) -> new DOMSource(parameters.get(href)));

Comment: using DOMSource is only a good input source if you need to work with the W3C DOM API as well, otherwise Saxon has its own native tree model that should perform better and consume less memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any Java object (including a `Stream`) by wrapping it in an `XdmExternalObject` (which is a subclass of `XdmValue`). But is it a good idea? What are you actually trying to achieve? A Stream is a mutable object (reading from the stream changes its state) and mutable objects and XSLT don't really play very well together. If we knew what you wanted to achieve we might be able to suggest a better design.

Comment: I am reading message from a queue , which is an xml. I do not want to store it in a file location , rather process(transform xml to other using xslt) the file on go .

Comment: Then pass it as a string, which is a native XDM data type and is immutable.

Comment: Thanks .Will try that